# Is the integral of the liminf of a function its lower integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis

Let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a bounded function. Let's define $\varphi:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $\varphi(x)=\liminf\limits_{t\to x}f(t)$. Is is true that $\varphi$ is integrable (in the Riemann sense) and $\int_a^b\varphi(x)\,dx=\underline{\int_a^b}f(x)\,dx$ (the lower integral of $f$)?

This is something that came into my mind while doing some real analysis exercises. Another guess I have is that instead of equality, the integral of $\varphi$ may only be less than or equal the lower integral of $f$. I know about Fatou's Lemma but I don't know if it can be used in this problem.